# Getting Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then") in shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I am working on setting up some shell scripts for backups. Everything is ok but I am getting syntax errors when I use if then statements.

Looking at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/if-else-statement.htm they use a simple if statements which works on the website as it has a try it pop section. When I copy the contents into a file save as .sh and try it on my ubuntu server (16.04.2 x64), I get Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "then")

The code from the website is below

```
#!/bin/sh
a=10
b=20

if [ $a == $b ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

To run on terminal I use

```
sh /path/to/file/script.sh
```

There are a few questions asked and answered but none of them seem to be the same as my case. Is there something I need to update on the server? If I use bash instead of sh it says unexpected token. Anyone had this issue?

If it may help, when I run in terminal, it does not seem to like empty spaces, full error is below

```
sh /var/www/check-day.sh
: not foundeck-day.sh: 4: /var/www/check-day.sh:
/var/www/check-day.sh: 10: /var/www/check-day.sh: Syntax error: "fi" 
unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Comment: Works for me.... just ran your code. Make sure you're copying and pasting correctly - not missing the `then`.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways Let me update the question, another issue is that it does not like blank spaces if that means something.

Comment: Using `=`rather than `==` is a bit more portable, depending on the `sh` implementation you're using, but if that were the problem you'd get a different error message. Is it possible that your file has Windows-style CR-LF line endings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has CRs in it. Use `dos2unix` to fix.